# Finding Avg/Sum of a Column Value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a nice Jitter plot of my data, but I'm looking to look further into the data by finding Mean/Sum/Median etc...

I don't know the syntax to separate the data by column value.

My date frame consists of 2 variables: Year (2010-2017) and Followers (Numeric)

Code I used:

```
ggplot(MyData, aes(factor(Date), Followers)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(color = factor(Date)))
```

This separated each Numeric data point into categorized groups of each year.

I was able to use `sum(MyData$Followers)` to get total Followers for all years.
As well as `count(MyData, 'Date')` To get frequency for each year.

But I'm not sure how to combine them to get total followers/avg followers for each individual year.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr`:

```
df <- MyData %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  summarize(Mean = mean(Followers), Count = n(Followers))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I still got total sum/avg instead of group avg/sum though. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you post the results of `dput(MyData)` into your question? If your data set is really large can you do `dput(MyData[1:x])` just making sure that the second number is an indice that includes at least a second year

Comment: Ahh okay all I had to do was add "n_distinct" instead of "n" and that fixed it. :)